# Run SML file but not be left in interactive mode

Tags: windows, sml

I am using New Jersey SML on Windows. If `test.sml` is an SML file I can execute it by running this at a Windows command prompt:

```
C:\> sml test.sml
```

I then get the usual SML output and a new SML command prompt.

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: Sat Sep 29 12:51:13 2012]
[opening hw1.sml]
val d2 = (1,1) : int * int
val d3 = (1,1) : int * int
val d4 = (2,1) : int * int
val d5 = (1,2) : int * int
val x7 = true : bool
-
```

What I would like instead is to be exited back to the Windows command prompt and not be left in the SML interactive mode.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you try:

```
sml <test.sml
```

Beyond that, using its compilation manager (CM) SML/NJ actually allows you to compile a program into binaries and run them separately. The [manual](http://smlnj.org/doc/CM/new.pdf) should be able to tell you more (see especially section 15 describing the ml-build command).

Answer (score 5):

Running SML/NJ that way, it will open the REPL (read-eval-print-loop). Thus it will wait for new declarations to interpret, until you tell it to exit.

Acording to the SML/NJ faq on [usage](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/FAQ/usage.html), then

> The OS.Process.exit function is the proper means of quiting sml from within a program.

It takes either `OS.Process.success` or `OS.Process.failure` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Also from the command line you can:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd> interrupts  (incase of loops that will not exit etc...)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Z</kbd> exits the REPL